# How do I mock nested methods in my angular unit test?

Tags: angular

I have this method with nested methods inside:

```
  private angularLocation;

  constructor(
    locationHelperService: LocationHelperService
  ) {
    this.angularLocation = locationHelperService.getLocation();
  }

  public redirectToDashboard() {
    const path = this.angularLocation.search();

    if (path.ref) {
      this.angularLocation.url(path.ref);
    } else {
      this.angularLocation.path('/dashboard');
    }
  }
```

I want to test that it redirects to the correct path.

I got this on my test:

```
    const mockLocationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocationHelperService', [
      'getLocation'
    ]);

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      / * other stuff here */
      providers: [
        { provide: LocationHelperService, useValue: mockLocationService },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

      mockLocationService.getLocation
      .and.returnValue({
        search: function() {
          return { path: { ref: '/other-page' } }
        }
      });
    });

    it('should setup permissions if login succeeded.', waitForAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      
      const loginButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#login-button');
      loginButton.click(); /* this click event triggers redirectToDashboard */

      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        /*some expectations here*/
      });
    }));
```

Why is the service undefined? I don't understand how to setup the return value of getLocation.
What did I do wrong? I am getting this error when I run my test.

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search')
    at redirectToDashboard
```

Comment: You're setting up the mock response _after_ you've constructed the component you're trying to test.

Comment: does it matter where i put it? what if i want to test another scenario where the search function returns another path? do i have to create another TestBed.createComponent() for that?

Comment: You should be able to, but you can also set a new return value on the mock.

Comment: It does matter if that means the component you're trying to test is calling the test double _before_ you set up the mock response, therefore getting the default value of `undefined` (which has no `search` or any other property)...

Comment: thanks man! You're right, i should've put it before.